# Как написать команду chmod для этого случая?

Tags: linux, консоль, chmod

Мне нужно создать директиву `company/users`
И не разрешать никому делать изменений . Я делаю это так chmod u+rx,g+rx,o+rx company/users. Но когда пытаюсь создать текстовый файл не получаю permission denied. Что тут не правильно?

Comment: Root юзер может сделать изменений, но мне нужно чтобы никто не смог.

Comment: `u+..., ... ` **добавляет** полномочия. Для  отмены записи используйте `u-w,...` или просто **`chmod a=rx company/users`** для **установки** всем (владелец, пользователи из группы и все остальные) только **чтения и  поиска** (для обычного файла `x` это исполнение,  а в случае каталога -- поиск в нем)

Comment: Однако, **root** в любом случае, какие права ни настраивай, будет в состоянии делать что угодно и с этим каталогом и с его содержимым. Система принципиально не ограничивает полномочия  рута на действия с файлами

Comment: у меня стоят такие полномочия когда использую ls -l company   dr-xrwxr-x root accountants accountants   то же самое для  lawyers но почему то я не могу создать файл используя пользователя группы которому принадлежит директива ю например user Tim принадлежит группе lawyers но не может создать файл в одноименной директиве что тут не правильною

Comment: Не знаю. У меня `cat /etc/issue` -- `Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia` вот такие команды в $HOME/tmp успешно проходят: `sudo bash` в нем `mkdit t-dir; chown :avp t-dir; chmod g+w t-dir; chmod u-w t-dir; exit` из user avp `ls -ld t-dir` выводит `dr-xrwxr-x 2 root avp 4096 Apr 30 17:59 t-dir` далее `echo hshsh >t-dir/1.txt; touch t-dir\1-txt` потом `echo 123 >>t-dir/1.txt; cat t-dir/1.txt`  тоже все успешно выполняются и выводит `hshsh
123`